# How to disable autoplay when launching a website using Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

Some website will autoplay a video or enlarge an image. How to stop it using Selenium with Python?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Tip: Do some reasearch yourself before asking here - it will help you avoid getting downvotes (some of the egos in here are very fond of downvoting...). Also, you need to write your question better. Include specific, examples, details etc.

Comment: Your code trials please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It really depends on the case, since your question is too general, I am supposing two cases:

1) you are talking about `autoplay` attribute of the `video` tag.
Setting `autoplay` to `false` doesn't help some videos will play anyway. See [this case in fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/evuhgfnb/)

One sure way would be to inject a script that stops all the videos, like this:

```
import selenium
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=other")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
#driver.get("https://blog.synq.fm/html5-video-looping-autoplay-on-ios-and-android#gist48620519")
driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/LaneigeHongKong/posts/1542227299146098%22')
sleep(5)
driver.execute_script('videos = document.querySelectorAll("video"); for(video of videos) {video.pause()}')
```

Also because the video are stopped you might want to add the controls (play, bar ,etc) in case you want to start them latter, in this case the JavaScript bit is like this:

```
videos = document.querySelectorAll("video"); for(video of videos) {video.pause(); video.controls = true}
```

The above case will not work if the `video` tag is in a shadow root element, but then hardly any general solution will work. There you will need a custom aproache.

2) you are talking about autoplay in general, unfortunately here there is no general solution, one way would be to save settings on the sites you would need to atutomate, I use the Chrome options user-data-dir in order to use folders as profiles, I run:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=selenium") 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("www.google.com")
```

You can do here the logins that check for human interaction, or change setting(ex: disable autoplay) I do this and then the cookies I need now every-time I start the Webdriver with that folder everything is in there. You can also manually install the Extensions and have them in every session.
Secon time I run, all the cookies are there:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=selenium") 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("www.google.com") #Now you can see  the cookies, the settings, Extensions and the logins done in the previous session are present here
```

The advantage is you can use multiple folders with different settings and cookies, Extensions without the need to load, unload cookies, install and uninstall Extensions, change settings, change logins via code, and thus no way to have the logic of the program break, etc Also this is faster than havin to do it all by code.

Comment: Thank you, Eduard. But I want to disable the autoplay. For example, when you browse "https://www.facebook.com/LaneigeHongKong/posts/1542227299146098", the video will start automatically. How to not to play it?

Comment: @Chan It happens that the first solution works for that particular link on Facebook? Just paste in console `videos = document.querySelectorAll("video"); for(video of videos) {video.pause(); video.controls = true}` and see for yourself.

Comment: The idea is once you have selected all the videos you can do whatever you want with them even remove them `videos = document.querySelectorAll("video"); for(video of videos) {video.parentElement.removeChild(video)}`

Comment: @Chan just tested on your link and it works I added an extra `sleep(5)` if the video still plays increase to more seconds, if it stops to late decrease it. `webdriver` will wait for the page to load by default with the `get()` method but I don't know what woo Facebook is doing to the page so that's why you need to add the `sleep`.